# Visual Studio Inclusion Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I just made a new project, and included iostream, and when I ran it, it gave me the error "No such file or directory". I might be missing something huge here, but it also doesn't work on templates. Does anyone know why?

This is the project:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did you name the source file?  did it have a .cpp file extension?

Comment: Please provide, in your question and not in comment, a small program that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score -1):

When you choose console aplication check the option: include precompiled header, most likely you created an empty project in which case you must manualy add the path to iostream file

in .vcxproj directory includes you should have: Include Directories $(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include; and Library $(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib

if you have these and stdafx.h include in cpp but still no path to iostream you should check PATH environment variable not to be broken or any of the variables $(VCInstallDir) $(WindowsSdkDir) $(FrameworkSDKDir)

Comment: I choose empty projects all the time, and the compiler can handle #include <iostream> just fine, because it has a special folder which it uses to lookup the headers